# How to deploy a asp.net core web application to azure b2c tenant?

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, azure-ad-b2c

I was able to redirect the login link to azure ad on my localhost, but I get a useless error message on the deployed version:

[image]

I created the ad b2c application and it looks lie this :

[image]

On visual studio, the asp.net core web project was created using the out-of-the-box way :

[image]

As you can see I also created the policies. Like I said, it works fine when I tested the same approach on localhost (instead of the app URL, I use https://localhost:45341/signin-oidc), but when I deploy, it does not work. What I am missing?

PD: The project I created is not using a windows server, but instead, linux, that might be the issue? I haven't found any tutorial online, all the ones out there are examples within localhost.

Answer (score 0):

As the error message says "For local debugging, development environment can be enabled by setting the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT environment variable to Development, and restarting the application".

You can just do like this simply to resolve this issue:

Go to Azure, click on your Web App –> "Configuration" –> click “+New application setting” and add the “ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT” and “Development”.

[image]

Don't forget to restart the application and wait a few minutes for it to take effect.